# Problem during transactional tests with SQLAlchemy, Pytest and FastAPI

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, pytest, fastapi

I'm having the following issue:

I'm setting a transactional setup database to test my endpoints of a FastAPI application. I'm using FastAPI, SQLAlchemy, and Pytest with PostgreSQL.
I'm also using factory boy to create some objects during my tests and the database is being cleaned after each test. The problem is that I have some classes as a dependency to get the current user by its JWT token (override_get_current_user and override_get_current_approver_user), but when these functions look into the db_session for the user it cannot find any instance in the database. These functions are inherited directly from the override_get_db by the Depends() function.

There are my files:

#conftest.py

```
import pytest
from fastapi.testclient import TestClient
from psycopg2 import OperationalError, ProgrammingError
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, event

from app.api.v1.routers.core.config import DEFAULT_PREFIX
from app.core.dependencies import (
    get_current_approver_user,
    get_current_user,
    verify_jwt_auth_token,
)
from app.database.base_model import Base
from app.database.dependencies import get_db
from app.database.utils import get_or_create
from app.main import app
from app.models.user import UserModel
from tests.core.auth import generate_token
from tests.core.config import Settings
from tests.core.database import session
from tests.core.database.dependencies import override_get_db
from tests.core.dependencies import (
    override_get_current_approver_user,
    override_get_current_user,
    override_verify_jwt_auth_token,
)


def db_prep():
    print("dropping the old test db…")
    engine = create_engine(f"{Settings.DATABASE_URL}")
    conn = engine.connect()
    try:
        conn = conn.execution_options(autocommit=False)
        conn.execute("ROLLBACK")
        conn.execute(f"DROP DATABASE {Settings.DATABASE_NAME}")
    except ProgrammingError:
        print("Could not drop the database, probably does not exist.")
        conn.execute("ROLLBACK")
    except OperationalError:
        print(
            "Could not drop database because it’s being accessed by other users (psql prompt open?)"
        )
        conn.execute("ROLLBACK")
    print(f"test db dropped! about to create {Settings.DATABASE_NAME}")
    conn.execute(f"CREATE DATABASE {Settings.DATABASE_NAME}")
    conn.close()
    print("test db created")


@pytest.fixture(scope="session")
def connection(request):
    db_prep()
    engine = create_engine(f"{Settings.DATABASE_URL}{Settings.DATABASE_NAME}")
    _connection = engine.connect()

    _connection.execute(
        f"DROP SCHEMA IF EXISTS {Settings.DATABASE_DEFAULT_SCHEMA} CASCADE;"
    )
    _connection.execute(f"CREATE SCHEMA {Settings.DATABASE_DEFAULT_SCHEMA};")

    def teardown():
        _connection.execute(
            f"DROP SCHEMA {Settings.DATABASE_DEFAULT_SCHEMA} CASCADE;"
        )
        _connection.close()

    request.addfinalizer(teardown)
    return _connection


@pytest.fixture(scope="session", autouse=True)
def setup_db(connection, request):
    Base.metadata.bind = connection
    Base.metadata.create_all()

    def teardown():
        Base.metadata.drop_all()

    request.addfinalizer(teardown)


@pytest.fixture(scope="function")
def db_session(connection, request):
    with connection.begin() as transaction:
        _session = session.testing_session()
        _session.begin_nested()

        @event.listens_for(_session, "after_transaction_end")
        def restart_savepoint(session, transaction):
            if transaction.nested and not transaction._parent.nested:
                session.expire_all()
                session.begin_nested()

        def teardown():
            session.testing_session.remove()
            transaction.rollback()

        request.addfinalizer(teardown)
        return _session


@pytest.fixture(scope="function")
def client() -> TestClient:
    """
    Overrides original functions and creates a test client for the application.
    """
    app.dependency_overrides[get_db] = override_get_db
    app.dependency_overrides[
        verify_jwt_auth_token
    ] = override_verify_jwt_auth_token
    app.dependency_overrides[get_current_user] = override_get_current_user
    app.dependency_overrides[
        get_current_approver_user
    ] = override_get_current_approver_user

    return TestClient(
        app,
        root_path=DEFAULT_PREFIX,
    )
```

#session.py

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.orm import scoped_session, sessionmaker

from tests.core.config import Settings

engine = create_engine(f"{Settings.DATABASE_URL}{Settings.DATABASE_NAME}")
testing_session = scoped_session(
    sessionmaker(autocommit=False, autoflush=False, bind=engine)
)
```

#base.py (factory boy)

```
from datetime import datetime

import factory

from app.database.base_model import Base
from tests.core.database.session import testing_session


class BaseFactory(factory.alchemy.SQLAlchemyModelFactory):
    class Meta:
        model = Base
        sqlalchemy_session = testing_session
        sqlalchemy_session_persistence = "commit"

    created_at = datetime.now()
```

#override_db.py

```
from tests.core.database import session


def override_get_db():
    """
    Gets testing database connection

    Yields:
        database: Testing database connection
    """
    try:
        database = session.testing_session()
        yield database
    finally:
        database.close()
```

#dependencies.py

```
import jwt
from fastapi import Depends, HTTPException, status
from fastapi.security.http import HTTPBasicCredentials
from sqlalchemy.orm import Session

from app.api.v1.biz.user import UserBiz
from app.core.dependencies import user_auth_token
from app.models.user import UserModel
from tests.core.config import Settings
from tests.core.database.dependencies import override_get_db


async def override_user_email_from_token(
    authorization: HTTPBasicCredentials = Depends(user_auth_token),
):
    token = getattr(authorization, "credentials")

    token = jwt.decode(
        jwt=token,
        key=Settings.SECRET_KEY,
        algorithms=[Settings.SECRET_ALGORITHM],
    )

    user_email = token.get("sub", {}).get("email")

    return user_email


def override_verify_jwt_auth_token(
    authorization: HTTPBasicCredentials = Depends(user_auth_token),
):
    """Receives the `Authorization` header and checks is its valid considering
    it's subject and ttl.

    Args:
        authorization (HTTPBasicCredentials, optional): Bearer JWT token.
        Defaults to Depends(HTTPBearer()).
    """
    token = getattr(authorization, "credentials")

    jwt.decode(
        jwt=token,
        key=Settings.SECRET_KEY,
        algorithms=[Settings.SECRET_ALGORITHM],
    )


def override_get_current_user(
    user_email: str = Depends(override_user_email_from_token),
    db_session: Session = Depends(override_get_db),
) -> UserModel:
    """Based on the JWT token gets the current logged user.

    Args:
        user_email (str, optional): Bearer
        JWT token. Defaults to Depends(override_user_email_from_token).
        db_session (Session, optional): Database session.
        Defaults to Depends(dependencies.get_db).

    Returns:
        UserModel: Current logged user instance
    """

    user_biz = UserBiz(db_session=db_session)
    user = user_biz.get_user_from_email(user_email=user_email)

    return user


def override_get_current_approver_user(
    user_email: str = Depends(override_user_email_from_token),
    db_session: Session = Depends(override_get_db),
) -> UserModel:
    """Based on the JWT token gets the current logged user with approver
    permissions.

    Args:
        user_email (str, optional): User email.
        Defaults to Depends(override_user_email_from_token).
        db_session (Session, optional): Database session.
        Defaults to Depends(dependencies.get_db).

    Returns:
        UserModel: Current logged user instance of approver user
    """

    user_biz = UserBiz(db_session=db_session)
    user = user_biz.get_user_from_email(user_email=user_email)

    if user.approver_group is None:
        raise HTTPException(
            status_code=status.HTTP_401_UNAUTHORIZED,
            detail="DCKSP_1202",
        ) from None

    return user
```

#the test itself

```
def test_master_approver_can_see_all_tickets_awaiting_approval(
    client, db_session
):
    """
    This test asserts that a master approver can see all tickets awaiting
    approval.
    """
    approver_group = ApproverGroupFactory(is_admin=True)
    functionality = FunctionalityFactory()

    ApproverGroupFunctionalityFactory(
        approver_group=approver_group,
        functionality=functionality,
    )

    ticket_functionality = TicketFunctionalityFactory(
        functionality=functionality
    )

    TicketFunctionalityUserFactory(
        ticket_functionality=ticket_functionality,
        approver_group=approver_group,
    )

    TicketFactory(
        functionalities=[ticket_functionality],
    )

    second_approver_group = ApproverGroupFactory()
    second_functionality = FunctionalityFactory()

    ApproverGroupFunctionalityFactory(
        approver_group=second_approver_group,
        functionality=second_functionality,
    )

    other_ticket_functionality = TicketFunctionalityFactory(
        functionality=second_functionality
    )

    TicketFunctionalityUserFactory(
        ticket_functionality=other_ticket_functionality,
        approver_group=second_approver_group,
    )

    TicketFactory(
        functionalities=[other_ticket_functionality],
    )

    approver_user = UserFactory(approver_group=approver_group)
    auth_token = generate_token(
        client_id=Settings.TEST_USER_CLIENT_ID,
        client_secret=Settings.TEST_USER_CLIENT_SECRET,
        email=approver_user.email,
        user_id=str(approver_user.id),
    )

    response = client.get(
        url=f"{DEFAULT_PREFIX}/tickets/awaiting_approval",
        headers={"Authorization": f"Bearer {auth_token}"},
    )

    items = json.loads(response.content).get("items")

    assert response.status_code == status.HTTP_200_OK
    assert len(items) == 2
```

The problem is that when the "override_get_current_user" function looks for the user, its db_session doesn't have it, but when the test goes back to the test function, I can find the user through the db_session.